# Firebase Recaptcha returns error of: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to setup Firebase SMS on React Native. I have two documents the first is a Firebaseconfig.js whose code is:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
console.log("Auth from getAuth" + " " + auth);
```

The next file is my Signup.js:

```
import { RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber } from "firebase/auth";
import { firebase } from "firebase/app";
import { auth } from "../FirebaseConfig";
const Signup = () => {
  console.log(auth);
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState(0);

  function onCaptchVerify() {
    if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
      window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
        "recaptcha-container",
        {
          size: "invisible",
          callback: (response) => {
            onSignup();
          },
          "expired-callback": () => {},
        },
        auth
      );
    }
    window.recaptchaVerifier.verify().then((response) => {
      onSignup();
    });
  }

  function onSignup() {
    onCaptchVerify();

    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;

    const formatPh = "+972" + phoneNumber;

    signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, formatPh, appVerifier)
      .then((confirmationResult) => {
        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
        console.log(confirmationResult);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

When I try to run my code and I click the button to run onSignup() I get an error of: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined. When I log the auth it comes back being populated and defined and I have all the firebase modules installed that I need, however I dont understand how to send the SMS authentication text. Any guidance would be great.